# How can I represent functions in a flowchart?

Tags: c, flowchart

I define some function in my [ANSI C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) program (simple program). How can I represent a function in a flowchart?

Comment: You need to provide more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a flowchart, a function can be anything: a state, an action that occurs while transitioning betwwen states, etc.  It all depends on how you have your flowchart organized.  I would recommend building your flowchart normally, then go back and add a function name to the description of anything that is implemented by a function.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, a flowchart is more of a functional description of your algorithm and not where you would "define" a function in the sense of your program.  Yes,  a functional aspect represented in your flowchart may directly map to a single function in your C program, but it may be that multiple functions or multiple threads are used to accomplish it as well.  The flowchart isn't where you would describe these.

In short, the flowchart is not where you should be "defining" functions for your C program.  It should be a high-level representation of functional aspects of your program, not the implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any direct symbol... You can create your function with the basic input /output/process symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, [Flowcharting a Get-ter](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337875/flowcharting-a-get-ter), which was answered with:

**NOTE**: Please don't upvote this answer but instead the original within the above link.

> Flowcharts represent flow of control, not flow of information.
>   Flowcharting formally captures steps and the linkages between them
>   that describe the transfer of the flow of control that are often based
>   on decisions: in particular, conditional branches and loops.
>
> Flow of control is about what is done or happens next, and (sadly) not
>   about the required data to perform that step.
>
> According to Wikipedia, there are some extensions for the flow of
>   data; however, they are basically limited to documents and files.
>
> Generally speaking, state is poorly represented in flowcharting; there
>   is virtually no notion of data, variables, scopes, lifetimes, or
>   types. So, data (and metadata about that data, such as allowed or
>   expected types) is mostly documented informally with human language
>   description in the text within individual steps of the flowchart.
>
> Input & Output in flowcharting is meant to indicate communication with
>   another independent and top-level process (even if it is just a later
>   running copy of one's self). As such this communication is about
>   reading/writing to disc or to a network.
>
> A getter does not qualify as input or output, which is to say
>   communication with another independent process, so I think that is
>   out. I don't think they even had getter's when flowcharting was first
>   applied to software design (circa 1950).
>
> You might look in to UML. – Erik Eidt Dec 12 '16 at 16:51

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good example of subprocess or function diagram from my CS studies. Basically one need to use additional Enter - Exit blocks to describe function context. And then reference it using sub-process block.

[flowchart diagram with sub-process example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhY7Y.jpg)

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer in text form, instead of posting links to external ressources